# Image comparison with color noise in OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, compare

I have a code:

```
def compare_frames(frame1, frame2): 
    # cropping ranges of two images
    frame1, frame2 = similize(frame1, frame2)

    sc = 0
    h = numpy.zeros((300,256,3))
    frame1= cv2.cvtColor(frame1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    frame2= cv2.cvtColor(frame2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    bins = numpy.arange(256).reshape(256,1)
    color = [ (255,0,0),(0,255,0),(0,0,255) ]

    for ch, col in enumerate(color):
       hist_item1 = cv2.calcHist([frame1],[ch],None,[256],[0,255])
       hist_item2 = cv2.calcHist([frame2],[ch],None,[256],[0,255])
       cv2.normalize(hist_item1,hist_item1,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
       cv2.normalize(hist_item2,hist_item2,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
       sc = sc + (cv2.compareHist(hist_item1, hist_item2, cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL)/len(color))
    return sc
```

It works, but if image have color noise (more darken/lighten tint) it's not working and give similarity equals is 0.5. (need 0.8)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

An image 2 is more darken than image 1.

Can you suggest me FAST comparison algorythm ignore light, blur, noise on images or modify that?

**Note:**

i have template matching algorythm too:

But it works slowly than i need although similarity is 0.95.

```
def match_frames(frame1, frame2):
    # cropping ranges of two images
    frame1, frame2 = similize(frame1, frame2)

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(frame1,frame2,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    return numpy.amax(result)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is one of the classic ones in computer vision and image processing. Many doctoral theses have been written and scores of papers in conferences and journals.

In short direct pixel comparisons will not work in this case.  A *transformation* of some kind is needed to take you to a different feature space.  You could do something simple or complex depending on the requirements you have in mind.  You could compute edges or corners.  One suggestion already mentioned is the FAST corner detection.  This would be a good choice as would SIFT etc... There are many others you could use but it will depend on how much the two images can vary and in what ways.

For example, if there is only going to be global color changes, tint, etc the approach would be different than if the images could be rotated or the object position changing in size (i.e. camera zoom).

Strictly speaking for the case you mention features such as FAST, SIFT, or even edges would work reasonably well.  Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28computer_vision%29 for more information

Answer (score 0):

Image patch descriptors (SIFT, SURF...) are usually monochromatic and expect black-and-white images. Thus, for any approach (point matching, frame matching...) I would advise you to change the color space to Lab or YUV first and then work on the luminance plane.

FAST is a (fast) corner detection algorithm. A corner is obviously insensitive to noise and contrast, but may be affected by blur (bad position, bad corner response for example). FAST does not include a descriptor part however, so your matching should then rely on geometric proximity. If you need a descriptor part, then you need to switch to one of the many other keypoint descriptors (SIFT, SURF, FAST + BRIEF/BRISK/ORB/FREAK...).